# Handling page source on Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-scraping, greasemonkey

I want to add a script via greasemonkey to browser so that I can get the page source of the web page in a file, then read and handle it.

My aim is to check whether the web-page contains hidden elements, iframes or other malicious content. I want to read the contents of the web-page, and if it contains such elements, it can give warning to the user.

Hope I'm clear..

Comment: I know the languages and basics of jquery, but I'm not able to understand how to extract the contents of web-page and handle them. I need suggestions on how it can be done..

Answer (score 0):

You have to traverse the DOM (Document Object Model). And then check all the elements to see if it is hidden and if it is one of the elements you consider malicious.

Look at this site for info on how you traverse the DOM:

http://javascript.info/tutorial/traversing-dom

Answer (score 0):

Well.. the answer to my question is -

```
if (document.querySelector)
{
 var frame=document.querySelectorAll("iframe")
 for (var i=0; i<frame.length; i++)
 {
     frame[i].onmouseover=function()
     {
          alert("iframe");
     }
 }

 var hyper=document.querySelectorAll("a")
 for (var i=0; i<hyper.length; i++)
 {
     hyper[i].onmouseover=function()
     {
            alert("hyperlink");
     }
 }
}
```